# application verifier DEBUG or RELEASE mode?

Tags: c++

I have a corruption memory heap with my application. I would like to use Application Verifier in order to find the bug.

I have some difficulties to find a tutorial on how use Application Verifier.

One of the first question I'm wondering is should I use my application in DEBUG or RELEASE mode ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, in debug mode with a debugger attached will be your first stop. This provides full run-time checks, more validation, and more accurate information on what is going wrong. Application Verifier can also signal the debugger to break and will output error information, so having a debugger attached is very useful.

After that, as Simon Richter noted, you'll want to run most of it again in release. Release builds typically don't have the same checks and don't watch for errors, so things are very likely to surface that weren't an issue in the debug build. There is some use for a sort of manual-debug or hybrid build, where you perform some of the checks and logging to make sure things don't go too far afield.

To use Application Verifier, you really just need to start it, add an application and enable to desired tests. When you run, it will create a log and send messages/breaks to a debugger if one is around.

Answer (score 1):

With the necessary experience in debugging, "Both" would be the right answer, as the differences between Debug and Release builds also give good hints about the source of the problem.

If you do not want to dive that deep into the inner workings of the compiler, then use the Debug version if the error appears there reliably.

Answer (score 0):

usually debug versions run the application verifier to find the bugs in the app.